# Lookup another table and multiply rows

Tags: sql

[image]

Trying to multiply Table A with Table B. In Table A column `Total` Ex: lookup `Activity 1` `STD Time` from `Table B` and `Activity 2` `STD time` from `Table B`

Comment: Which RDMS like SQL Server, MySQL etc., you are using?

Answer (score 0):

For performing multiplication you would need to use `union all`:

```
select *, (tb.STDTime * t.Time) as MultiTime
from (
    select TeamName, 'Activity1' as Activity, Activity1 as Time
    from tableA UNION ALL
    select TeamName, 'Activity2' as Activity,  Activity2 as Time
    from tableA UNION ALL
    select TeamName, 'Activity3' as Activity,  Activity3 as Time
    from tableA UNION ALL
    . . .
    select TeamName, 'Activity7' as Activity,  Activity4 as Time
    from tableA
) t inner join tableB tb on tb.Activity = t.Activity;
```